# mysql: Get row index count in mysql_fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How can I get the row index count while looping in mysql_fetch_assoc()?

I dont want to use an external counter like this:

```
$counter= 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo 'Row '.$counter;
$counter ++;

}
```

Is there any built in MySQL function to get the current row index in the loop?

EDIT:

The reason I don't want to use an external variable is that I switched from using one method to another to loop through a set of MySQL results.

I was using:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

for($x=0;$x < $num;$x++){

    echo 'Row '.$x;
    // $field = mysql_result($result,$x)

}
```

and now the MySQL_fetch_assoc() method above.

I mainly switched for keeping everyhing at it's simpliest. The for method make it pretty easy to keep track of the row index but the MySQL_fetch_assoc require the input of another variable.

Comment: any reason you don't want to use a PHP variable to count?

Comment: Please check the EDIT on the above question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither mysql DB nor mysqli driver has such a feature.

So, just use an "extrenal" counter - there is not a single problem with it.

Regarding switching methods, let me suggest you to switch to [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info). It would apparently fulfill your desire to simpler and cleaner code:

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$stm->execute();
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
?>
<table>
<? foreach ($data as $i => $row): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?=$i+1?></td>
    <td>
      <a href="news.php?<?=$row['id']?>">
        <?=$row['title']?>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
<? endforeach ?>
```

Comment: PDO seems great. Thanks for the insight. Is it a built-in extension in PHP?

Comment: Yes, it's one of two recommended extensions, and it's proved to be way more usable than mysqli. You can refer to the link I provided for the details

Comment: +1 for PDO, but FWIW it isn't always enabled in PHP.  You can check with http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others, it seems like an artificial requirement.

The only alternative I can think of is to build the row count into your SQL query:

```
SELECT (@row:=@row+1) AS rownum, m.*
FROM (SELECT @row:=0) AS _init 
STRAIGHT_JOIN mytable AS m
WHERE ...
```

But that seems like it's more complex than simply using the PHP variable to count.

---

Re your edit:

You can use the for loop and also mysql_fetch_assoc():

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

for($x=0;$x < $num;$x++){

    echo 'Row '.$x;
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

}
```

Since you're fetching rows sequentially anyway, there's no reason to use mysql_result() to fetch the *n*th row.  That function is useful if you want to fetch rows out of order, either skipping or backing up in the result set.